# Elasticsearch find exact word in document

Tags: elasticsearch, exact-match

I need to find documents with an exact match of the word inside the text

For example, I search with the word "Rave" I want to find not "Travel aaa" or "bbb brave ccc" but only "Rave" as a separate word inside "ggg Rave hhh"

The same I want to achieve with several words of search. For example, I have a "Bas taste" search word I want to get documents only when "Bad taste" inside document next to each other so "aa bas taste bb" and not "cc bad dd taste ee"

I am using that field with custom analyzers (ngram tokenizer and some filters inside).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please add which query you are currently trying ? also, please provide index mapping.

Comment: `match` and `match_phrase` would be the ideal candidates searching exact words, but of course it depends on your custom analyzers and what they do exactly. feel free to share more information regarding your index settings and mappings.